# Load more records based on row numbers using Entity Framework Core and C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have a shopping site; when I click on "load more", I want to load another set of records, probably 10 more. I'm trying to use the row numbers to fetch the records. I saw an example using stored procedures, but I want to use Entity Framework Core.

Here is my code - I get this error:

```
Processing of the LINQ expression 'DbSet<Product>
.OrderBy(t => t.ID)
.Select((t, i) => new { 
    row = i, 
    ID = t.ID, 
    Category = t.Category, 
    Description = t.Description, 
    Name = t.Name, 
    PicPathLeft = t.PicPathLeft, 
    PicPathMain = t.PicPathMain, 
    PicPathRight = t.PicPathRight, 
    Price = t.Price, 
    Size = t.Size
 })' by 'NavigationExpandingExpressionVisitor' failed. This may indicate either a bug or a limitation in EF Core. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101433 for more detailed information.
```

This is my code:

```
public JsonResult GetMoreProducts(int count)
{
   var start = ((page - 1) * pageSize) + 1;
   var end = page * pageSize;

   var query2 = db.Product.OrderBy(t => t.ID)
                    .Select((t, i) => new
                    {
                        row = i,
                        t.ID,
                        t.Category,
                        t.Description,
                        t.Name,
                        t.PicPathLeft,
                        t.PicPathMain,
                        t.PicPathRight,
                        t.Price,
                        t.Size
                    }).ToList().Where(x => x.row <= end && x.row >= start);

   var dataContainer2 = query2.Take(pageSize).ToList();
   return Json(dataContainer2);
 }
```

Or do I need to set anything at the startup services before it can work?

Thanks
Tim

Comment: @Mahmoud t is the model, while i is the index, why i'm using an anonymous type is just because i want to send the result as json.

Comment: If stored procedure solve your task you can call and fetch result from stored  procedure. see  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/ef/core/querying/raw-sql. 
The index of item is not supported by your provider (in select) - it is impossible to convert

Comment: The index of item is not supported by your EF provider (in select) - it is impossible to convert your Linq to correct SQL query.  You can first select count of rows and then construct query using Take and Skip Linq functions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to use a row number, once the records are ordered, you can just use the Skip() and Take() methods. In this case, calculate the number of records to skip by (pageSize * pageNumber). I also recommend calling ToList() once at the very end, that will execute the query and ensure you load the minimum set of results into memory.

```
    public JsonResult GetMoreProducts(int pageNumber, int pageSize)
    {
        var query2 = db.Product
            .OrderBy(t => t.ID)
            .Select(t => new
            {
                t.ID,
                t.Category,
                t.Description,
                t.Name,
                t.PicPathLeft,
                t.PicPathMain,
                t.PicPathRight,
                t.Price,
                t.Size
            });

        var results = query2
            .Skip(pageSize * pageNumber)
            .Take(pageSize)
            .ToList();

        return Json(results);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks @sspaniel, i tried something similar before, probably i missed something out. Thanks